# Trigger AWS CodePipeline by GitHub release Webhook

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline

AWS CodePipeline now supports GitHub WebHook, but by default
every time code is pushed(changed) on the master branch, CodePipeline is triggered.

However, I only want it to run when I actually publish a release.
So, I manually configured the auto-generated GitHub WebHook as follows:
(Uncheck Pushes, check Releases)

[image: webhook]

but after the configuration, CodePipeline is not kicked any more.
(When I check Pushes again, it starts watching every pushes again)

Does it only watch Pushes action?

If it does, is there any other way to kick CodePipeline by GitHub release actions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CodePipeline's webhooks were designed to handle push events, but I think there's no reason why you shouldn't be able to configure the CodePipeline webhook to trigger on release events. No information from the webhook invocation is actually used as part of the source action, so you could trigger it from anything.

The reason it's not working is probably because of how your webhook filters are configured.

Take a look at the [`ListWebhooks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_ListWebhooks.html) API to see how your webhook is configured.

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_WebhookDefinition.html) describes how the filters and authentication configuration is used to match github events to decide whether to trigger a pipeline execution or not.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!
Like you said, it was the filter that prevented my release webhook. ({"jsonPath": "$.ref", "matchEquals": "refs/heads/{Branch}"}) only exists in push webhook body.
After I changed it to fit release webhook(like this -> {"jsonPath": "$.action", "matchEquals": "published"}), it worked like a charm!!

Comment: No problem! I enjoy developing features for CodePipeline and seeing creative ways our customers use them 

Comment: @sora, could you please clarify, how to edit that JSON?

Comment: @MatthewSainsbury could you, please, provide short FAQ how to edit these values?

Comment: Take a look at the PutWebhook API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_PutWebhook.html). You might also be interested in ListWebhooks (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_ListWebhooks.html)

Comment: Neither `create` or `publish` github webhooks actually contain the commit that the tag points to, so how can this work with CodePipeline when you want it to act on that commit? The `push` event does, but you'd have to do a partial match on `$.ref == "refs/tags/my-tag"`, then extract the tag name from that, which CodePipeline webhooks don't appear to support (only `matchEquals` with `{Branch}`). So how would that work?

Comment: Sora/@MatthewSainsbury- I tried modifying the filter using cli to {"jsonPath": "$.action", "matchEquals": "published"}. But still the Pipeline doesnt trigger for tags, it only works for commits. Can you tell me if any other change needs to be made to make it trigger CodePipeline for Tags using webhooks?