# Trigger CodePipeline when a tag is created in Github

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github, webhooks, aws-codepipeline

I am using Github Version 1 as Source in CodePipeline (Cannot use Version 2 due to organization restrictions). I need CodePipeline to be triggered only when a tag is created and not for every commit. I have setup the Trigger using Webhooks option in CodePipeline and in the webhooks, I have selected 'Let me select individual events' under which I have check marked `Branch or tag creation` and `Releases`. But CodePipeline doesnt trigger when I create a new tag. When I use the `Pushes` option, it works fine and triggers the pipeline on a commit.

When I check the `Recent Deliveries`, I can see that I am getting 200 response for publish actions, but the pipeline doesnt trigger.

I even tried creating the webhooks via CLI as mentioned in this stack overflow, but it didnt work:
[Trigger AWS CodePipeline by GitHub release Webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52516087/trigger-aws-codepipeline-by-github-release-webhook)

Can anyone help me configure the webhook to trigger the AWS CodePipeline when a tag is created?

Answer (score 0):

The good news is, it is possible! The bad news is, you need additional instrumentation outside of AWS. And it's full of hacks.

CodePipeline's github integration only seems to work with branches - it doesn't have a way of looking for tags.

CodePipeline IS able to watch an ECR repo for changes, but it only watches for a specific tag (default is latest).

What I wanted was to be able to create a tag with a certain prefix (eg. the name of the environment that I want to deploy to) and have it land there automatically.

I created a `git tag` workflow on CircleCI (github actions should also work) and had it push the `latest` tag for the ECR repo linked to my environment (eg. staging).

./.circleci/config.yml

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  deploy-staging:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/aws:2023.09
    steps:
      - checkout
      - setup_remote_docker:
          docker_layer_caching: true
          version: 19.03.13
      - run:
          name: build-and-deploy
          command: |
            ./.circleci/push-ecr.sh "staging" "latest"
workflows:
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - deploy-staging:
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore: /.*/
            tags:
              only: /^staging\/.*$/
```

./.circleci/push-ecr.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ECR_REPO="$1"
TAG="$2"

ECR_URL="$AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/$ECR_REPO"
ECR_RESOURCE="$ECR_URL:$TAG"

docker build -t $ECR_RESOURCE .
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
docker push $ECR_RESOURCE
```

Codepipeline's `Source` phase has 2 parts:

1. the ECR repo (which triggers the pipeline)
2. the github repository (where the buildspec.yml file lives).

Codepipeline's `Build` phase reads from both input sources, the github repository is set as the `primary` source which is how it finds the buildspec.yml
the buildspec.yml file's only purpose is to create an artifact for the deploy phase. I would have loved to skip the build phase entirely, but if it doesn't find the artifact in s3 then it won't even try to deploy.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - printf '[{"name":"%s","imageUri":"%s"}]' $ECS_CONTAINER_NAME $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json

artifacts:
  files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Codepipeline's deploy phase didn't need any additional considerations

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSXkx.png)